# DIV block creation in magento 2.1 using xml layout

Tags: xml, magento2

I am integrating my own custom template in magento2.1. I have tried to add div container into footer block.

I tried below code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer custom">

        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
<container name="footerContainer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cart-container" before="-">
</container>
</referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

This xml code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

We need to declare like below

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
<container name="footerContainer" htmlTag="div" htmlId="cart-container-id" htmlClass="cart-container" before="-">
</container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

> magento2 seems to render a container only if the children generate a
>   html output

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/110958/61877

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the below code inside the file path:
**app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
  <referenceContainer name="footer">
    <container name="footerContainer" htmlTag="div" htmlId="cart-container-id" htmlClass="cart-container" before="-" />
  </referenceContainer>
```